# how to define schema for custom address type for multiple addresses in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, schema

For multiple addresses in mongodb, we generally store address in array.

```
address:[
{
"type" : "home",
"primary" : false,                             
"streetaddress" : "Some",                             
"locality" : "Farnborough",
"region" : "England",
"formatted" : "Farnborough, United Kingdom",
"country" : "United Kingdom",
"location" : [
-0.752615,
51.2868939
]
},
{
"type" : "business",                         
"locality" : "London",
"region" : "England",
"formatted" : "The Gherkin, London, United Kingdom",
"primary" : false,
"streetaddress" : "30 St Mary Axe",
"country" : "United Kingdom",
"location" : [
-0.08030649999999999,
51.51449179999999
]
}
]
```

But to fetch specific address by key eg. home or business, we need to  loop through array. Is there any alternative way other than defining as below

> ```
> {
>       home_address:
>               {
>                 "streetaddress" : "Some",          
>                 "locality" : "Farnborough",
>                 "region" : "England",
>                 "formatted" : "Farnborough, United Kingdom",
>                 "country" : "United Kingdom",
>                 "location" : [
>                               -0.752615,
>                               51.2868939
>                              ]
>             },
>     business_address : {
>                "locality" : "London",
>                "region" : "England",
>                "formatted" : "The Gherkin, London, United Kingdom",
>                "primary" : false,
>                "streetaddress" : "30 St Mary Axe",
>                "country" : "United Kingdom",
>                "location" : [
>                               -0.08030649999999999,
>                               51.51449179999999
>                            ],
>             },
>     primary_address : "home_address"
>
>     }
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by "primary" key or, to put it another way, what are criteria you want to get an address by?

Comment: updated question. query relates to how we can write json format for this scenario. where we want to fetch "home" address without looping into address array.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you know exactly you're going to query a certain value of an array and you know the said value, it is good to turn it into a sub-document with the value as the key.

Similar to what you have above:

```
"address": {
    "type_home": { "street": ... }, 
    "type_business": {"street": ...},
    "primary": "type_home", 
    "available": ["type_home", "type_business"]
}
```

Flexible schema is part of MongoDB features, and you should utilise this to help optimise your application usage. The above schema would help to query a particular address faster than looping over an array.

You may be benefited from seeing more of [data models examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models/)